# Как передать значение по ссылке в С?

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Есть 2 метода

```
void foo(int num)
{
    printf("\nstart num is : %d \n", num);

    num+=4;

    printf("finish num is : %d \n", num);
}
```

второй

```
void boo(int num)
{
    printf("second val is : %d", num);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("val : %d", i); 
    }

    putchar('\n');  
}
```

и метод `main`

```
int main()
{
    putchar('\n');
    foo(num);
    boo(num);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

и вот лог который получается

```
start num is : 0 
finish num is : 4 
second val is : 0
```

Как передать `num` по ссылке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте указатель, типа

```
void foo(int *num)
{
    printf("\nstart num is : %d \n", *num);

    (*num)+=4;

    printf("finish num is : %d \n", *num);
}

...

foo(&num);
```

Comment: с Вашего позволения, я добавлю, что в С нет ссылок. Ссылки это уже С++